# Storing database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

Is there some tool that can store for me the database structure, say in some xml file or something like that.

And later from the code it can generate for me the sql query for this database creation ?
Currently I am working with MySQL , but it probably does not matter .

Just I not want to maintain my self all those things.

Comment: I forgot to ask if you were using php. because if you are not i will delete my answer

Comment: @Neal , sorry  I am not using it :(

Comment: I think I am going to keep the answer here for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I have used MySQL Workbench to take care of issues like this. If you download Workbench (assuming you don't have it already) from http://wb.mysql.com/ you will have the option to "Create an EER diagram from an existing database." This will create an EER diagram which is a good visual presentation of the database with which you are working. The .mwb file that you can then save can be loaded and then "forward engineered" into local/external database.

Mysqldump is another alternative to use at the command line. It will, by default, dump out the entire schema structure and contained data. However, if you are just looking for database structure including views and routines and you do not care about the data itself then you need to throw some extra parameters into the command.

In my experience Mysqldump is quick and easy whereas EER diagrams are easier to share with others and then forward engineer back onto other DBs from the Workbench application.

**EDIT**

You should note that just because you export the database create table queries to a .sql file or .mwb file that you can't just copy and paste the text into another platform (Microsoft SQL, Oracle, etc) and expect it to work. Syntax across different versions of SQL is (obviously) different.

Comment: After I used there the modeling tool and designed the schema , how I can apply it on actual database ?

Comment: Open up the EER model, click on "Database" at the top, and then click on "Forward engineer." You will be prompted for connection information and whatnot and then the database will be built.

Answer (score 1):

**THE FOLLOWING ANSWER USES PHP**, *I am keeping it here for future users.*

I wrote code specifically to do that (in PHP):

```
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());

$allTables = Array
    (
      //put all table names in this array
    );
foreach($allTables as $tbl){
    define($tbl, $tbl);
}
$clm = '$columns';
$inds = '$indexes';
$query = "SHOW TABLES IN {$dbname}";
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tables[] = $row["Tables_in_{$dbname}"];
}

//TO GET ARRAY FOR TABLE DISPLAY:
$cols = array();
foreach($tables as $tbl){
//    echo "<br/>".
    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tbl";
    $cols[$tbl] = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $cols[$tbl][] = array('Field'=>$row['Field'],
                              'Type'=>$row['Type'],
                              'Null'=>$row['Null'],
                              'Default'=>$row['Default'],
                              'Extra'=>$row['Extra'],
                        );
    }
}
$index = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$dbname}';
"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $index[$row['TABLE_NAME']][] = array('INDEX_NAME'=>$row['INDEX_NAME'],
                          'COLUMN_NAME'=>$row['COLUMN_NAME'],
                          'INDEX_TYPE'=>$row['INDEX_TYPE'],
                          'INDEX_NAME'=>$row['INDEX_NAME'],
                          'SEQ_IN_INDEX'=>$row['SEQ_IN_INDEX'],
                    );
}
//echo "<pre>";print_r($index);
//exit;
//TO GET THE ARRAY VARIABLE
echo "<pre>
&lt;?php
$clm = Array (";
foreach ($cols as $key=>$tbl){
echo "
    $key => Array (";
    foreach($tbl as $col){
        echo "
        Array ( ";
        foreach($col as $k=>$val){
            echo "
            '$k' => \"$val\",";
        }
        echo "
        ),";
    }
    echo "
    ),";
}
echo "
);";
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>
$inds = Array (";
foreach ($index as $key=>$tbl){
echo "
    $key => Array (";
    foreach($tbl as $col){
        echo "
        Array ( ";
        foreach($col as $k=>$val){
            echo "
            '$k' => \"$val\",";
        }
        echo "
        ),";
    }
    echo "
    ),";
}
echo "
);
?>";
echo "</pre>";
```

Paste the result to this in a php file (called `currentDB.php`).

Then in another file is where the creation happens with the file you created:

```
define('BY_COL', 'column');
define('BY_IND', 'index');
$allTables = Array
    (
      //put all table names in this array
    );
foreach($allTables as $tbl){
    define($tbl, $tbl);
}

include_once 'currentDB.php';
$query = "SHOW TABLES IN $dbname";
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tables[] = $row["Tables_in_$dbname"];
}

$checkTables = checkTables($tables);
echo "THE FOLLOWING TABLES <b>ARE</b> IN THE DB: <br />
    <pre>";print_r(array_diff($allTables,$checkTables));echo "</pre><br />";
if($checkTables){
    echo "THE FOLLOWING TABLES <b>ARE NOT</b> IN THE DB: <br />".
//    "<pre>";print_r($checkTables);echo "</pre><br />";
    "";
    createTables($checkTables);
    $query = "SHOW TABLES IN $dbname";
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tables[] = $row["Tables_in_$dbname"];
}

}

//TO GET ARRAY FOR TABLE DISPLAY:
$cols = array();
foreach($tables as $tbl){
//    echo "<br/>".
    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tbl";
    $cols[$tbl] = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $cols[$tbl][] = array('Field'=>$row['Field'],
                              'Type'=>$row['Type'],
                              'Null'=>$row['Null'],
                              'Default'=>$row['Default'],
                              'Extra'=>$row['Extra'],
                        );
    }
}
$checkTables = checkCols($cols);

if($checkTables){
    echo "THE FOLLOWING COLS <b>ARE DIFFERENT</b> IN THE DB: <br />".
//    "<pre>";print_r($checkTables);echo "</pre><br />".
    "";
    alterTable($checkTables);
}
$index = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbname';
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ONE:".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $index[$row['TABLE_NAME']][] = array('INDEX_NAME'=>$row['INDEX_NAME'],
                          'COLUMN_NAME'=>$row['COLUMN_NAME'],
                          'INDEX_TYPE'=>$row['INDEX_TYPE'],
                          'INDEX_NAME'=>$row['INDEX_NAME'],
                          'SEQ_IN_INDEX'=>$row['SEQ_IN_INDEX'],
                    );
}
$checkTables = checkIndexes($index);

if($checkTables){
    echo "THE FOLLOWING INDEXES <b>ARE DIFFERENT</b> IN THE DB: <br />".
//    "<pre>";print_r($checkTables);echo "</pre><br />".
      "";
    alterTable($checkTables,BY_IND);
}
//echo "<pre>";print_r($indexes);echo "</pre><br />";

function  checkTables($array){
    $tbls = $GLOBALS['allTables'];
    $diff = array_diff($tbls,$array);
    if($diff){
        return $diff;
    }
    return array();
}

function  checkCols($array){
    $cols = $GLOBALS['columns'];
    $diff = array_diff_no_cast($cols,$array);
    if($diff){
//        echo "HI<br />";
        return $diff;
    }
    return array();
}

function checkIndexes($array){
    $ind = $GLOBALS['indexes'];
    $diff = array_diff_no_cast($ind,$array);
    if($diff){
//        echo "HI<br />";
        return $diff;
    }
    return array();
}

function createTables($tables){
    $cols = $GLOBALS['columns'];
    $ind = $GLOBALS['indexes'];

    foreach($tables as $t){
        $thisCols = (isset($cols[$t])?$cols[$t]:array());

        $thisInd = (isset($ind[$t])?fromIndex($ind[$t]):array());

        $create = "CREATE TABLE `$t` (\n";
        foreach($thisCols as $k=>$c){
//            echo "<pre>$k\n{$c['Default']}</pre>";
            if($c['Default']=='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'){
//                echo "IN HERE";
                $c['Extra'] = " ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
            }
            $create .= "`{$c['Field']}` {$c['Type']} ".
                    (($c['Null']=='NO')?'NOT NULL':'')." ".
                    ((strlen($c['Default'])>0)?"DEFAULT ".
                    (is_quoted($c['Default'])?"'{$c['Default']}'":"{$c['Default']}"):'').
                    "{$c['Extra']}";
            if(count($thisCols)!==($k+1)){
                $create .= ",\n";
            }
            else
                $create .= "\n";
        }
        $i = 0;
        foreach($thisInd as $k=>$c){
            if($i == 0){
                $create .= ",\n";
            }
            if($c['INDEX_NAME']=='PRIMARY'){
                $create .= "PRIMARY ";
            }
            else{
                $iName = explode("_",$c['INDEX_NAME']);
                if(array_search("UNIQUE",$iName)){
                    $create .= "UNIQUE ";
                }
            }
            $create .= "KEY ".
                (($c['INDEX_NAME']=='PRIMARY')?'':"`{$c['INDEX_NAME']}`")." ({$c['COLUMN_NAME']})";
            if(count($thisInd)!==($i+1)){
                $create .= ",\n";
            }
            else
                $create .= "\n";
//            echo "<pre>";print_r($c);echo "</pre>";
            $i++;
        }
        $create .= ");";
//        echo "<pre>$create</pre>";
        mysql_query($create) or die("ERROR CREATE:".mysql_error());
        echo "CREATED $t<br />";
    }
//    die;
}


function fromIndex($ind){
    $return = array();
    foreach($ind as $i){
        $return[$i['INDEX_NAME']]['INDEX_NAME'] = $i['INDEX_NAME'];
//        echo $i['COLUMN_NAME']." -- <br/>".
        $return[$i['INDEX_NAME']]['COLUMN_NAME'] = (isset($return[$i['INDEX_NAME']]['COLUMN_NAME'])?"{$return[$i['INDEX_NAME']]['COLUMN_NAME']}, `{$i['COLUMN_NAME']}`":"`{$i['COLUMN_NAME']}`");
    }
//    echo "<pre>";print_r($return);echo "</pre>";
//    die;
    return $return;
}
function alterTable($table, $type = BY_COL){
//    echo "<u>";

    switch ($type){
        case BY_COL:
//            echo BY_COL;
            $tbls = $GLOBALS['cols'];
            $realTbls = $GLOBALS['columns'];
//            echo "<pre>";print_r($table);echo"</pre>";
//            die;
            foreach($table as $k=>$t){
//                echo
//                $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $k";
//                echo "<br />";
                foreach($t as $ky=>$col){
//                    echo
                    if($ky == 0){
                        $after = 'FIRST';
                    }
                    else {
                        $after = "AFTER `{$realTbls[$k][$ky-1]['Field']}`";
                    }
                    $primary = false;
                    if($col['Default']=='CURRENT_TIMETAMP'){
                        $col['Extra'] .= " ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
                    }
                    if($col['Extra'] == 'auto_increment'){
                        $query2 = "ALTER TABLE  `$k` ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `{$col['Field']}` )";
                        $query3 = "ALTER TABLE `$k` CHANGE COLUMN `{$col['Field']}`
                             `{$col['Field']}` {$col['Type']} ".($col['Null']=='YES'?'NULL':'NOT NULL').
                            ((!empty($col['Default']))? ' DEFAULT '.(is_quoted($col['Default'])?"'{$col['Default']}'":$col['Default']):'').
                            " {$col['Extra']}".
                            " $after;";
                        $primary = true;
                        $col['Extra'] = "";
                    }
//                    echo
                    $query = "ALTER TABLE `$k` ".(field_in_array($tbls[$k],$col['Field'])?"CHANGE COLUMN `{$col['Field']}`":"ADD COLUMN").
                            " `{$col['Field']}` {$col['Type']} ".($col['Null']=='YES'?'NULL':'NOT NULL').
                            ((!empty($col['Default']))? ' DEFAULT '.(is_quoted($col['Default'])?"'{$col['Default']}'":$col['Default']):'').
                            " {$col['Extra']}".
                            " $after;";
//                    echo "<br/>";
                    mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR CREATE: $query".mysql_error());
                    if($primary){
                        mysql_query($query2) or die("ERROR CREATE: $query2".mysql_error());
                        mysql_query($query3) or die("ERROR CREATE: $query3".mysql_error());
                    }
                    echo "ADDED $k: {$col['Field']}";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
//                if($k == 'sessions'){
//                    echo "<pre>$ky:\n";print_r($tbls[$k]);die;
//                }
            }
            break;
        case BY_IND:
//            echo BY_IND;
            $tbls = $GLOBALS['index'];
            foreach($table as $k=>$t){
                $addTbls= fromIndex($table[$k]);
                $thisInd = (isset($tbls[$k])?fromIndex($tbls[$k]):array());
//                echo "<pre>$k:\n";print_r($addTbls);
                foreach($addTbls as $added){
                    $beg = "INDEX";
                    if($added['INDEX_NAME']=='PRIMARY'){
                        $beg = "PRIMARY KEY";
                        $added['INDEX_NAME'] = '';
                    }
                    else{
                        $iName = explode("_",$added['INDEX_NAME']);
                        if(array_search("UNIQUE",$iName)){
                            $beg = "UNIQUE ".$beg;
                        }
                    }
//                    echo
                    $query = "ALTER TABLE `$k` ".(field_in_array($thisInd,$added['INDEX_NAME'],'INDEX_NAME')?"DROP INDEX `{$added['INDEX_NAME']}`, ":'')."ADD $beg `{$added['INDEX_NAME']}` ({$added['COLUMN_NAME']})";
                    mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR CREATE:".mysql_error());
                    echo "ADDED $k: {$added['INDEX_NAME']}";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
//            die;
            break;
    }
//    echo "</u><br />";

}

function is_quoted($str){
    if(is_numeric($str))
        return false;
    if($str == 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        return false;
    return true;
}

function field_in_array($arr, $field, $type = 'Field'){
    foreach($arr as $val){
//        echo "HERE: $field, $type";
//        print_r($val);echo "<br/>";
        if($val[$type]==$field){
//            echo "HI";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

   ##################################
   #    FUNCTION - multidim diff    #
   ##################################

function array_diff_no_cast(&$ar1, &$ar2) {
   $diff = Array();
   foreach ($ar1 as $key => $val1) {
       foreach($val1 as $k=>$val2){
          if (!isset($ar2[$key]) || array_search($val2, $ar2[$key]) === false) {
             $diff[$key][$k] = $val2;
          }
       }
   }
   return $diff;
}
```

Comment: Pretty impressive, but with the lack of auto type-casting and other difficulties that are presented by php->mysql why would you create a php script that does exactly what other tools (MySQL Workbench, Mysqldump) already do better? Curious to know what motivated you to create this

Comment: @MoarCodePlz. we did it so that we could just run the 1st script and give our client a new `currentDB.php` file and all they have to do is put it in the appropriate spot and run the update script (the second part of the code)

Comment: @MoarCodePlz -- this code also updates all indexes and the like.

Comment: @NightWalker, i am sure it is. It took a while to fully debug ^_^, i think for the most part the kinks are out. (as you can tell i commented out alot of my debug messages)

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database with [Mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html). The web page has all the details on how to use it.

If you want the SQL to create the table, you can use:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname
```

If you have data, foreign keys, stored procedures and views in your database then the [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-sql-scripts.html) can forward reverse all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL and others, you might want to try the [DESCRIBE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility.  It will create a copy of your database in SQL format.  (Note to avoid a problem I ran into: Be sure to run it with --routines if you want to also capture your stored functions and procedures!)

A typical command would look something like this:

```
mysqldump --routines -Q --opt -p -u username databasename >savefile.sql
```

Also, for large databases, these files can get quite large.  You might also want to consider gzipping them or otherwise compressing them on the fly, using something like:

```
mysqldump --routines -Q --opt -p -u username databasename | gzip >savefile.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

use `phpMyAdmin` u can export your structure to `XML`,`SQL`,`CSV` and many other by using export option